# Calling a method inside listview item click in android

Tags: android

I need to call a method inside the item click of a ListView. The app stops responding when running. I'm trying to run a method called getSubVitals inside the class GetSubVitals(another class). How do I call such a method? Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class VitalListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    GetSubvitals getSub;
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    public static List<String> vitalList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vital_list);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String status = intent.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        if(status.equals("true")){
            new GetParentVitalName().execute();
            //Log.d("check list",vitalList.get(0));
            Log.d("Tag", "Execute complete");
            //populateListView();
            Log.d("Tag", "Populate complete");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_vital_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void populateListView(List<String> vitalList) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new MyListAdapter(vitalList);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vitalsListView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public MyListAdapter(List<String> vitalList){

            super(VitalListActivity.this, R.layout.vital_list_layout, vitalList);
            Log.d("Tag", "super okay");
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            //Making sure we've a view to work with(may have been given null
            Log.d("TAG","Inside get view");
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null)
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.vital_list_layout, parent, false);

            String currentVital = vitalList.get(position);

            //Fill the view

            TextView vitalText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById((R.id.vitalTextView));
            vitalText.setText(currentVital);

            return itemView;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return vitalList.size();
        }
    }

    private class GetParentVitalName extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... params){

            String responseText = null;

            HttpClient httpClient = ServiceHelper.getHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://test.gogch.com/gch-restful/vitals/custome/added/parentvitals");
            Log.d("KMN", "Sucess");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                Log.d("DFGH","Success again.");
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                Log.d("Http Post Response V", Integer.toString(statusCode));
                responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.d("Http Post Response V", responseText);

            }
            catch(ClientProtocolException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responseText;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String responseText){

            if (responseText != null){
                try {
                    JSONArray vitalsArray = new JSONArray(responseText);
                    for(int i =0;i<vitalsArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject vitalsObject = vitalsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String parentVitalName = vitalsObject.getString("parentVitalName");
                        vitalList.add(parentVitalName);
                        Log.d("YGVJ",vitalList.get(i));
                    }
                    populateListView(vitalList);
                    registerListClick();
                }
                catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void registerListClick(){

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vitalsListView);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
                String vitalName = vitalList.get(position);
                JSONArray subVitalsArray = null;
                Log.d("HGFD","sadsadsad");
                String responseText  = getSub.getSubVitals(vitalName);
                Log.d("HGFD",responseText);
                if (responseText != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray vitalsArray = new JSONArray(responseText);
                        for (int i = 0; i < vitalsArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject vitalsObject = vitalsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String parentVitalName = vitalsObject.getString("parentVitalName");
                            if (parentVitalName.equals(vitalName)) {
                                subVitalsArray = vitalsObject.getJSONArray("subVitals");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                ArrayList<SubVitals> subVitalList = new ArrayList<SubVitals>();

                for(int i =0; i<subVitalsArray.length();i++){
                    try {
                        //map.clear();
                        JSONObject obj = subVitalsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String unit = obj.getString("unit");
                        String subVitalId = obj.getString("subVitalId");
                        String subVitalName = obj.getString("subVitalName");
                        String unitId = obj.getString("unitId");
                        SubVitals subVitals = new SubVitals();
                        subVitals.setUnit(unit);
                        subVitals.setSubVitalId(subVitalId);
                        subVitals.setSubVitalName(subVitalName);
                        subVitals.setUnitId(unitId);
                        //map.put("unit",unit);
                        //map.put("subVitalId",subVitalId);
                        //map.put("subVitalName", subVitalName);
                        //map.put("unitId", unitId);

                        subVitalList.add(subVitals);
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                //DFragment dFragment = DFragment.newInstance(subVitalList);
                // Show DialogFragment
                //dFragment.show(fm, "dialog");
                //String message = "You clicked" + vitalName;
                //Toast.makeText(VitalListActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is what logcat says:

```
04-07 18:31:46.759  29734-29734/com.cinch.getvitalsapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cinch.getvitalsapp, PID: 29734
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.cinch.getvitalsapp.tasks.GetSubvitals.getSubVitals(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.cinch.getvitalsapp.activities.VitalListActivity$1.onItemClick(VitalListActivity.java:186)
```

Comment: What is the line 186 in your VitalListActivity?

Comment: Use asyntask to get list detail and show progress dialog for user interaction.

Comment: never mind vitalList, that part is working fine.

Comment: "getSub.getSubVitals(vitalName);" Where do you initialize the getSub variable?

Comment: Eh. I didn't initialize, that was problem. Please don't mind for making this stupid thread. I'm new to this. I used to be a SAS programmer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the error output your getSub variable is null ....

--> either you make the getSubVitals method static  or you initialize getSub